# How to avoid hard coding .vscode/launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

Twice now I've wasted time because making a change to the TargetFramework and/or RuntimeIdentifier elements in launch.json has resulting in a mismatch between what is being build and what is run when I press F5, i.e.

```
 "program": "${workspaceFolder}/System.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/System.Web.dll",
```

Changing TargetFramework from 2.0 to 2.1 left the /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0 folder with stale binaries as I forgot to change lauch.json (and making things more confusing once the project file has been changed, clean doesn't remove the previous build as it only cleans the netcoreapp2.1 folder - so I only get a lauch error when I fully removed /bin)

Is there a better way to specify the "program": element, i.e. ideally

```
 "program": "${workspaceFolder}/System.Web/bin/Debug/{TargetFramework }/{RuntimeIdentifier }/{target}",
```

So if a developer changes them in the proj file, the lauch configuration stays valid?